# Count values from a column, where the values are the same as defined

Tags: postgresql

I want to count all the values where it is the same as --> lid <--. I haven't found a good answer on Google.

The column's title: membership.
The column is stored in: member.

This is the actual column:

[image]

This is the code I had, but I get 0 in return:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT functie
      FROM bestuursleden
    WHERE functie='lid'
  ) AS functie;
```

So when the count is executed, the value in a new column (with as title 'count') should be --> 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL is case-sensitive, you are using a wrong reference, it should be `Lid`

Comment: Ofcourse... I feel dumb. The DISTINCT should also be removed. Ty for the quick answer.

Comment: I made the same mistakes when I started to work with PostgreSQL =)

Comment: I find it really hard to find out all this stuff. Don't know the right words to Google sometimes.